# Create a Google maps link to a specific location

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I'm looking to create a link to a specific location using latitude and longitude for positioning, however I would also like to be able to add a marker onto the map as well, at the same location.

This is not using the Java or Static maps API, just want a link pointing at maps.google.com

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's very straightforward. Just use the following link, changing the latitude and longitude for yours. The z is the zoom index, you can play with it to get where you want.

http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&hq=&ll=35.028028,-106.536655&z=13

I got this information by clicking on the "Link" button in the right hand corner above a map. This will also allow you to get the latitude and longitude for a location.

I don't know of a good way to make a marker on Google Maps, through the UI anyway.  Right click on a point and select "What's Here?" to create a marker, but it will be to the closest thing (business, intersection, address, etc). This essentially performs a search with the latitude and longitude and returns whatever is closest to your search. A URL to do that would be:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.128061,-106.535561&ll=35.126517,-106.535131&z=17

With the q (for query I believe) being the coordinates where you want your marker.

A more effective method, if you are trying to send a link to a specific address would be to search for the address in Google Maps, which will give you a marker on the exact address and then use the "Link" button to get the URL for sharing.

Comment: Cool, is there any way to add a marker as well?

Comment: The search method works perfectly for me, cheers!

Comment: @sgriffinusa To get the long/lat quickly, enalbe "LatLng Marker" in your `Google Maps Lab` setting

Comment: Additions: The encoding parameter (ie=UTF8) can be ommitted. For marker see Petra's answer below. Unlike you really fancy the new maps, I would add an ouput=classic.

Comment: I would use "center map here" rather than what's here, that way you get precise coordinates unrelated of whatever is nearby.

Comment: see more detailed explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9919251/444255

Answer (score 9):

as mentioned above, the link has to contain coordinates but can also contain description: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=description+(name)+%4046.090271,6.657248

In case you need to place multiple markers on the map, you will have to use some of the online tools, for example http://www.hamstermap.com and then choose QUICK MAP.

Comment: This solution fit my need the best!

Comment: Seems not to work anymore. The description and name are not displayed by Google Maps now.

Answer (score 4):

Do the following with the latest Google Map (as of 2015-10-15):

Select the location by clicking it:
[image]

Click the link with latitude and longitude, you will get the map with the location marked:
[image]

You can copy the link after verifying the map.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (it will definitely work with a pointer to your location on map):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=39.211374,-82.978277+(My+Point)&z=14&ll=39.211374,-82.978277
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a marker to a map, you can use the [My Maps](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=21670&topic=21676) feature of Google Maps.

Follow the instructions in the link above to use My Maps. Add a marker for the location that you're interested in sharing, then click the Link button in the upper-right corner; that link can be used to bring someone directly to that location and will include the marker you placed there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it.

- Install `Google Maps Lab` 's `LatLng Marker` for your Google Maps account
- Search for a place & use `Drop LatLng Marker` to any location you want.
- Click on the marker and copy the longtitude+latitude. (Here's [a very good post](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5519/the-easy-way-to-find-latitude-and-longitude-values-in-google-maps/) on how to do this.)
- Create the shared link by pasting the text as below
  http://maps.google.com/maps?z=18&q=`<long/lat text here>`

  E.g.
  http://maps.google.com/maps?z=18&q=10.8061,106.7130

I don't see why it would be so difficult for the Google Maps Team add a `Get Link` button, hopefully it will be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Google Maps URL Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

It shows how to perform specific actions like Search, Directions, Display a map etc

Comment: This is almos a link only answer. Please extend a bit your description, like including a simple example or how you used that guide to do what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the "new" google maps, select your location and then the cog-wheel icon in the bottom right. in the popup choose "Share and embed map".

That will tell you that you can simply copy the URL from the address bar. But it also gives you the option of a shortened URL.

Answer (score -2):

Use online tools like [linkonmap.com](http://linkonmap.com) to generate in seconds a link to a full screen map pointing to your location and even show the shortest route to your address.