# How do I get a link to a specified location in a given Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to use the new Google Map engine. I've created a new map where I have several markers. Now I would like to have a permalink to one of this markers.

By clicking on that link the user should be redirected to that map and to that specific marker on the map. How do I achieve this?

Comment: not the same problem but you can get some ideas from here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/create-a-google-maps-link-to-a-specific-location?rq=1

Comment: I do not know how to use that information to my specific case. I would like to have a link to one of my map.

Answer (score 2):

In the new Google Map, if you click a location on the map, it loads the location below the top-left search bar with the latitude and longitude as well.

[image: screen shot after clicking point on the map]

Once you click on the GPS coordinates, it loads the exact location of that point. So you can use the generated link. (Example: `https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=38%C2%B0+52.648'%2C+-77%C2%B0+2.051'&data=!4m14!2m13!1m12!3m8!1m3!1d24135!2d-77.0584227!3d38.8809387!3m2!1i1205!2i746!4f13.1!4m2!3d38.8774667!4d-77.0341833`)

You can do the same for your marker unless what you want is a link to the marker on that specific map. I don't think that is available as a feature at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for your scenario, but usually, in the new maps, clicking on a marker fills in the address bar with the direct link to that marker.

Comment: Already tried but it does not work (unless there is some more clicking you have to do that I do not know)